# Validate form with ISSET when using js delay function

Tags: javascript, php, forms, post, isset

I am trying to validate if the correct form is being sent with `isset()`, but this validation is not `TRUE` when a javascript delay is being applied. How come? What is the best way to check if the correct form was submitted via the `POST` method? See my code below. Maybe a hidden field would do the trick, but I actually really would like to know why the below code is not going through.

```
<script type="text/javascript">
window.addEventListener('load', function onload(){
var ccform = document.getElementById('cc_form');
if(ccform){    
    ccform.addEventListener('submit', function before_submit(e){
        setTimeout(function wait(){
            // After waiting, submit the form.
            ccform.submit();
        }, 2000);

        // Block the form from submitting.
        e.preventDefault();
    });
 }
});
</script>
<?php
if ($_SERVER['REQUEST_METHOD'] == 'POST' && isset($_POST['cc_form_submit'])) {  
    //Send the form
    //Not working
    echo 'ready to send!';  
}
if ($_SERVER['REQUEST_METHOD'] == 'POST') {  
    //Send the form
    //Working
    echo 'ready to send without ISSET!';  
}
?>
<form action="" method="post" class="cc_form" id="cc_form"> 
    <button class="cc_form_submit" type="submit" name="cc_form_submit">Send!</button>
</form>
```

Comment: u want to submit your form by using jquery after `delay(2000)` ? automatically

Comment: No? After clicking the submit button. Currently I have multiple forms on the same page and I want to do an extra validation of the correct form is being processed with the $_POST method.

Comment: use action if you have multiple forms. or ajax

Comment: or use hidden value and check in isset()

Comment: or u can use input type="button" instead of <button>

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your example, there are so many possible solutions:

**Solution 1:**

You can use a hidden value inside your form and then check this value in `isset()` method like:

```
<form method="post">
  <input type="hidden" name="form1" />
  <button>Submit</button>  
</form>

<form method="post">
  <input type="hidden" name="form2" />
  <button>Submit</button>  
</form>

<?php
if(isset($_POST['form1'])){
    // do somthing
}

if(isset($_POST['form2'])){
    // do somthing
}
?>
```

**Solution 2:**

You can use input type submit instead of `<button>` like:

```
<form method="post">
  <input type="submit" name="form1">
</form>

<form method="post">
  <input type="submit" name="form2">
</form>

<?php
if(isset($_POST['form1'])){
    // do somthing
}

if(isset($_POST['form2'])){
    // do somthing
}
?>
```

**Solution 3:**

You can use different action for multiple `<form>` like:

```
<form method="post" action="form1.php">
</form>

<form method="post" action="form2.php">
</form>
```

**Edit:**

As per your comment
*don't know why if ($_SERVER['REQUEST_METHOD'] == 'POST' && isset($_POST['cc_form_submit'])) { is not working.*

Its not working because, you are using `name=` attribute with `<button>`, in this case solution 2 will work for you.

Comment: Thanks, I was aware these solutions just don't know why `if ($_SERVER['REQUEST_METHOD'] == 'POST' && isset($_POST['cc_form_submit'])) { ` is not working.

Comment: @RobbTe: because <button> will not work with name, you need to use input type submit solution 2...